# What's wrong with tokio unix socket server/client?

Tags: rust, unix-socket, rust-tokio

I have a server that broadcast messages to connected client, though the messages doesn't get delivered and my tests fails.

I'm using the following

```rust
use anyhow::Result;
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};
use std::process::Stdio;
use std::sync::Arc;
use tokio::io::AsyncWriteExt;
use tokio::net::{UnixListener, UnixStream};
use tokio::sync::broadcast::*;
use tokio::sync::Notify;
use tokio::task::JoinHandle;
```

This is how I start and setup my server

```rust
pub struct Server {
    #[allow(dead_code)]
    tx: Sender<String>,
    rx: Receiver<String>,
    address: Arc<PathBuf>,
    handle: Option<JoinHandle<Result<()>>>,
    abort: Arc<Notify>,
}

impl Server {
    pub fn new<P: AsRef<Path>>(address: P) -> Self {
        let (tx, rx) = channel::<String>(400);
        let address = Arc::new(address.as_ref().to_path_buf());

        Self {
            address,
            handle: None,
            tx,
            rx,
            abort: Arc::new(Notify::new()),
        }
    }
}

/// Start Server
pub async fn start(server: &mut Server) -> Result<()> {
    tokio::fs::remove_file(server.address.as_path()).await.ok();

    let listener = UnixListener::bind(server.address.as_path())?;

    println!("[Server] Started");

    let tx = server.tx.clone();
    let abort = server.abort.clone();
    server.handle = Some(tokio::spawn(async move {
        loop {
            let tx = tx.clone();
            let abort1 = abort.clone();
            tokio::select! {
                _ = abort.notified() => break,
                Ok((client, _)) = listener.accept() => {
                    tokio::spawn(async move { handle(client, tx, abort1).await });
                }
            }
        }
        println!("[Server] Aborted!");

        Ok(())
    }));

    Ok(())
}
```

my handle function

```rust
/// Handle stream
async fn handle(mut stream: UnixStream, tx: Sender<String>, abort: Arc<Notify>) {
    loop {
        let mut rx = tx.subscribe();
        let abort = abort.clone();
        tokio::select! {
            _ = abort.notified() => break,
            result = rx.recv() => match result {
                Ok(output) => {
                    stream.write_all(output.as_bytes()).await.unwrap();
                    stream.write(b"\n").await.unwrap();
                    continue;
                }
                Err(e) => {
                    println!("[Server] {e}");
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
    }
    stream.write(b"").await.unwrap();
    stream.flush().await.unwrap();
}
```

my connect function

```rust
/// Connect to server
async fn connect(address: Arc<PathBuf>, name: String) -> Vec<String> {
    use tokio::io::{AsyncBufReadExt, BufReader};

    let mut outputs = vec![];
    let stream = UnixStream::connect(&*address).await.unwrap();
    let mut breader = BufReader::new(stream);
    let mut buf = vec![];
    loop {
        if let Ok(len) = breader.read_until(b'\n', &mut buf).await {
            if len == 0 {
                break;
            } else {
                let value = String::from_utf8(buf.clone()).unwrap();
                print!("[{name}] {value}");
                outputs.push(value)
            };

            buf.clear();
        }
    }

    println!("[{name}] ENDED");
    outputs
}
```

This what I feed to the channel and want to have broadcasted to all clients

```rust
/// Feed data
pub fn feed(tx: Sender<String>, abort: Arc<Notify>) -> Result<JoinHandle<Result<()>>> {
    use tokio::io::*;
    use tokio::process::Command;
    Ok(tokio::spawn(async move {
        let mut child = Command::new("echo")
            .args(&["1\n", "2\n", "3\n", "4\n"])
            .stdout(Stdio::piped())
            .stderr(Stdio::null())
            .stdin(Stdio::null())
            .spawn()?;
        let mut stdout = BufReader::new(child.stdout.take().unwrap()).lines();
        loop {
            let sender = tx.clone();
            tokio::select! {
                result = stdout.next_line() => match result {
                    Err(e) => {
                        println!("[Server] FAILED to send an output to channel: {e}");
                    },
                    Ok(None) => break,
                    Ok(Some(output)) => {
                        let output = output.trim().to_string();
                        println!("[Server] {output}");
                        if !output.is_empty() {
                            if let Err(e) = sender.send(output) {
                                println!("[Server] FAILED to send an output to channel: {e}");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        println!("[Server] Process Completed");
        abort.notify_waiters();

        Ok(())
    }))
}
```

my failing test

```rust
#[tokio::test]
async fn test_server() -> Result<()> {
    let mut server = Server::new("/tmp/testsock.socket");

    start(&mut server).await?;

    feed(server.tx.clone(), server.abort.clone()).unwrap();

    let address = server.address.clone();
    let client1 = connect(address.clone(), "Alpha".into());
    let client2 = connect(address.clone(), "Beta".into());
    let client3 = connect(address.clone(), "Delta".into());
    let client4 = connect(address.clone(), "Gamma".into());

    let (c1, c2, c3, c4) = tokio::join!(client1, client2, client3, client4,);
    server.handle.unwrap().abort();
    assert_eq!(c1.len(), 4, "Alpha");
    assert_eq!(c2.len(), 4, "Beta");
    assert_eq!(c3.len(), 4, "Delta");
    assert_eq!(c4.len(), 4, "Gamma");

    println!("ENDED");
    Ok(())
}
```

Logs:

```
[Server] Started
[Server] 1
[Server] 2
[Server] 3
[Server] 4
[Server] 
[Delta] 1
[Gamma] 1
[Alpha] 1
[Beta] 1
[Server] Process Completed
[Server] Aborted!
[Gamma] ENDED
[Alpha] ENDED
[Beta] ENDED
[Delta] ENDED
```

Comment: That's a lot of code, but you haven't actually explained what the problem is.

Comment: sorry about that, the problem is the test fails. the broadcast doesn't deliver the messages to clients

Comment: I guess that your `feed` function finishes even before any of your clients is started. Maybe try adding a `sleep()` before launching the `echo`? Not the most trustworthy solution but it may help you diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 0):

well, not an answer but I just want to suggest to use task::spawn to generate a JoinHandle from a function, then, say your handle could be:

```
 fn handle(mut stream: UnixStream, tx: Sender<String>, abort: Arc<Notify>) -> JoinHandle {
  let mut rx = tx.subscribe();
  let abort = abort.clone();
  task::spawn( async move {
    loop {
        tokio::select! {
            _ = abort.notified() => break,
            result = rx.recv() => match result {
                Ok(output) => {
                    stream.write_all(output.as_bytes()).await.unwrap();
                    stream.write(b"\n").await.unwrap();
                    continue;
                }
                Err(e) => {
                    println!("[Server] {e}");
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
    }
    stream.write(b"").await.unwrap();
    stream.flush().await.unwrap();
})
}
```

I mean, I did not tested this, but I see a sort of duplication in the code above, like 2 loop, 2 select! and twice the abort check